# Running Python CGI on Cloud9

Tags: python, cgi, cloud9-ide

I can get Python CGI programs to run in other environments but would value help getting to "hello world" with the Cloud9 environment.

My simple programs runs fine, but I cannot get the HTML/web version of even a simple program.

The run gives me a suggestion of:
Your code is running at https://workspacename-username.c9.io.
Important: use os.getenv(PORT, 8080) as the port and os.getenv(IP, 0.0.0.0) as the host in your scripts!

But I do not know what to do with that.

My simple code follows. I also tried to run it as filename.cgi, but that does not work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print "<html>"
print "<head><title>My first CGI program</title></head>"
print "<body>"
print "<p> It works!! </p>"
print "</body></html>"
```

Comment: Are you running the built-in runner? Are the above lines being printed out on to the console? A bit more detail regarding how you're running the code (or setting up apache to serve cgi) would help figure out a solution.

Comment: I have tried the python runner and the built-in PHP-CGI runner. I tried to run Apache from the terminal and load CGI libraries, but no dice. Is there a special runner build I should use on Cloud9 for Python-CGI? That would make the world much simpler!! Thanks!

Comment: Please send an email at support@c9.io with your username and workspace name and I'll try to take a look

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Flask first, you can do it by the command:

```
$ sudo easy_install Flask
```

your code should be smth like this:

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    html=  "<html>"
    html+= "<head><title>My first CGI program</title></head>"
    html+= "<body>"
    html+= "<p> It works!! </p>"
    html+= "</body></html>"
    return html

app.run(host = os.getenv('IP','0.0.0.0'), port=int(os.getenv('PORT',8080)))
```

After you start application, you'll see

```
Your code is running at https://workspacename-username.c9users.io.
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

now you can open https://workspacename-username.c9users.io, it will work